# How do I exit or jump out of a UINavigationController to a totally separate controller which happens to me my root controller?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have 3 tabs on my UITabBarController
Home

Add Person

More

To get to a settings page an admin must tap More they are taken to a UINavigationController root view with a list of static rows. Then if they scroll to settings and tap but aren't logged in a login modal will pop up.

Upon entering correct login credentials the user is taken to the next view in the UINavigationController. There is a log out button on that page. When this button is tapped I'd like the user to be completely taken out of the UINavigationController. I've tried popping back to rootcontroller in the stack but it acts quite strange.

I'm just thinking it would be best to take the admin back to the home tab controller. Is there a way to do this properly instead of creating a segue from the logout button to my home main controllers view?

Comment: You really need to improve your question. Try to add some diagrams with the view/viewController hierarchy, the various screens and navigations. It's quite hard to understand it all like this.

Comment: Will do, as I'm actually confusing myself too. Working on it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what your situation is as your explanation is a bit ambiguous, but anyway, you can redefine all your viewController hierarchy by assigning a new rootViewController to the appDelegate window:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = ...
```

Comment: I'm am getting this error: "Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted." I have a navigation controller which has a table is embedded inside of (menu table controller). On that table there is a "Settings" row that takes me to another table. Which have rows that take me to one more view each. Without being logged in you can never get past the "Settings" row as intended. Now when a user is logged in if they go back to the "menu table controller" then click on settings again I get the error above and everything messes up.